# Order email cron schedule doen't work

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have been trying everything to get order emails to work on a new Magento 1.9.2.1 installation. Despite everything being enabled under System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails and setting up a proper cron in cPanel, nothing ever happens. I have setup the same exact cron in cPanel for another installation and it works fine. Nothing I do seems to matter.

The cron_schedule table seems to periodically re-populate with new schedule_id's but they always show as "pending", and executed_at and finished_at are all null. The core_email_queue table has all the unsent emails there (with null in the "processed_at" fields).

Nothing appears in the exception or system logs.

Comment: Try use [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to check cron routines and run it manually. "From" emails are correctly configured in System > Settings > Sales > Sales Emails?

Comment: It was my understanding that Aoe_Scheduler was not compatible with 1.9. Yes, emails are properly configured in Sales Emails settings.

Comment: does reset password email work? Are you sure that is not an smtp problem?

Comment: Aoe_Scheduler is compatible with 1.9.1.0 (I tested). I'm not sure about 1.9.2.1. Maybe a smtp problem (by @AntoninoBonumore)?

Answer (score 1):

Then you might be affected by a Magento bug. Open the file cron.php (back it up before editing) in the root directory of Magento and look for (around line 47):

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

After this line, add:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```